# ASP.Net: How can I replace duplicated theme changing C# code to a single class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've written some code that changes the visual appearance of a page through a drop down list which swaps between five Themes I've set up. The setting is also saved in a cookie so it remains consistent between sessions. This all works fine in a page and I can duplicate the effect by copying the code to other pages but this is bad practice as it uses the same code in multiple locations. The code resides on a code behind .cs file with a function running when the page loads and another when the list is changed:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)//only runs when page first loads not on postback reload
    {
      //activeThm is the current theme for the page
      string activeThm = Page.Theme;
      //thmCook is the cookie storing the theme setting, userThm is the cookie value storing the theme the user wants
      HttpCookie thmCook = Request.Cookies.Get("userThm");//reads variable from cookie
      if (thmCook != null)
      {//test if cookie is present
        activeThm = thmCook.Value;//sets active theme to value in cookie
      }
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(activeThm))
      {
        ListItem item = ListThm.Items.FindByValue(activeThm);//finds a list item that matches the active theme
        if (item != null)
        {
          item.Selected = true;//sets list to match active theme
        }
      }
    }
  }

  protected void ListThm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    HttpCookie thmCook = new HttpCookie("userThm");//cookie reference called thmCook created, cookie is called userThm
    thmCook.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);//cookie set to expire after 3 months
    thmCook.Value = ListThm.SelectedValue;
    Response.Cookies.Add(thmCook);//adds cookie
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());//reloads current page
  }
```

I've tried copying the code into a new class but don't know how to link the references to the dropdown list in the code to the external web page that calls the function. I tried using the sender argument like 'sender.ListThm' but it doesn't work.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction and save me duplicating a load of identical code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code you posted inside a User Control e.g. `ThemeChooser.ascx`. The User Control will only contain the `ListItem` that shows the available themes. With this approach you will only need to put the user control in every page you want, but the code will only exist in one place.

I believe that you will not need to make any code changes.

Comment: Or you can add it to your master page.  Depends on how you have it all structured.  One page to rule them all...   The usercontrol gives you the code in a single place, the master page gives you implementation in a single place.

Comment: @AdamHeeg Good point, the use of the master page is the preffered way to do. But if the OP had a master page, then the page design would practically "force" him to put it in the master page, thus not having the issue in the first place.

Comment: Good point, hopefully he considers it now  :)  Master pages are to asp.net what the printing press was to books - almost.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answers - the .ascx facility was exactly what I wanted and is sure to be generally useful. I do have a master page implemented, but getting advice on how to use both these features in an efficient manner is very helpful. Many thanks everyone.